# How to crop and show external image with specific size?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, crop

I get image url via API. It usualy have 360x200 but sometimes 233x350 etc..

I would like to crop them all to specific size 260x186. And show them using

```
  <%= image_tag image_url if hotel.images.first %>
```

I dont want to store this images.

Answer (score 1):

To crop them, I think you're going to need rmagick and image_magick.

If you just want to shrink them and display them, I'd suggest defining a CSS class and using it

```
<%= image_tag image_url, :class=>'my_class' if hotel.images.first %>
```

Comment: Just want to add that if you are going to use rmagick and image_magick you will have to store them locally, however it will give you all the control on the image size you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can crop, shrink, or stretch the images using css.  The problem is that if the aspect ratios are different,  the image will be distorted if you shrink or stretch,  or the image won't completely fill the target image size,  or you'll loose some of the source image if you crop.  Plus,  if you don't know the image size ahead of time,  that limits your ability to do anything intelligent.  This article discusses three techniques,  I'm sure one will work for you:

http://cssglobe.com/post/6089/3-easy-and-fast-css-techniques-for-faux-image